# Calling phtml in _construct() in magento2

Tags: magento2

How to call the template in the `construct()` in Magento 2 as we used to call in Magento1.

```
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->setTemplate('custom_folder/myfile.phtml');
}

protected function _toHtml() {
    return parent::_toHtml();
}
```

Can we call the myfile.phtml in layout file?

or is there way to call in `_construct()`?

Answer (score 1):

In your block file,

```
protected function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->setTemplate('Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml');
}
```

Check for `_construct()` method not confused with `__construct()`.

You can set your `Namespace_ModuleName :: path/to/template.phtml` in `setTemplate` function.

Like: `Vendor_Module::catalog/product/template.phtml`.

Comment: Both will work, but i would recommend doing this in an override of the _prepareLayout method. Semantically this is the correct method to set the template in.

Comment: And about the _toHtml()? no change rite?

Comment: there is no change required in `_toHtml()`